# how to use DateValue function dynamically in libreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Normally I can use DateValue function. But when I try to make it dynamic and select any cell for Datevalue function's argument it show error. May be I don't know actual format for using dynamic DateValue function.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP0EJ.png)

for example : I try to use DateValue in cell 3A according to B1(month) and B2(year) and day always 1

Comment: The question does not give enough details. What is in the cell you selected, and what is the formula? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. For a working example, if cell B1 contains `'2021-08-05` then `=DATEVALUE(B1)` will correctly produce a numerical result.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [**DATE() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_date.html) instead of the [**DATEVALUE() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03030102.html)

```
=DATE(B2;B1;1)
```

or for your format of month

```
=DATE(B2;FIND(B1;"   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec ")/4;1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
First method show me #VALUE!
Second method works.

Comment: The first method assumes that the month is indicated not by a word, but by a number from 1 to 12